# How to setup Artifactory active directory authentication with tree hyphens via LDAP?

Tags: ldap, artifactory, hostname, hyphenation

I am trying to set up Artifactory with LDAP authentication.

Unfortunately the hostnames of our AD-Servers contain three hyphens.

The Artifactory Web Frontend doesn't accept more than one hyphen in the "LDAP URL" field.

Example:

```
ldap://vm---ad01.envdevel.lan:389/dc=envdevel,dc=lan
```

Error message:

```
"Invalid LDAP URL"
```

Do you know a way to use the above-mentioned LDAP-URL?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the URL validation is only present in the webapp, so you can bypass it by creating the LDAP entry through the REST API.

Something like

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -T ldap.conf "http://server:8081/artifactory/api/ldap"
```

Where the LDAP configuration file (ldap.conf) looks like:

```
{
    "userDnPattern": "",
    "emailAttribute": "mail",
    "ldapUrl": "ldap://vm---ad01.envdevel.lan:389/dc=envdevel,dc=lan",
    "autoCreateUser": false,
    "ldapPoisoningProtection": true,
    "enabled": true,
    "search": {
        "searchBase": "ou=XXXXX",
        "searchSubTree": true,
        "managerDn": "cn=XXXXX,ou=XXXXX,o=XXXXX",
        "searchFilter": "uid={0}",
        "managerPassword": "XXXXXX"
    },
    "key": "test"
}
```

I obviously cannot test it here (no URL like this), all I can say is that the entry is created and may work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We will test this as soon as possible.

Comment: >It appears that the URL validation is only present in the webapp

Comment: >It appears that the URL validation is only present in the webapp .          Any chance, this will be fixed by the Artifactory developers?

Comment: Did you give this a try?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. I keep you posted as soon as we had time to test it.